# Remove button hover state after jQuery / CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css, button, css-animations

I scoured the site and the web but could not find an answer to this.

I'm using a `<button>` tag with some jQuery to reveal a registration form with a click function. The click triggers the button to animate to the side using a CSS3 transformX.

The problem is, the button still remains in the :hover state even thought the cursor is no longer over the button. It looks pretty stupid like this because the :hover state changes the button color, and it happens in all browsers I tested so far. Only after the cursor moves does the :hover state end.

I tried using `.unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout');` and `$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')` but neither work. I tried placing these right after the click function and also in the callback after the css animation.

I'm new to jQuery so maybe this is obvious, but I can't figure it out. Code could probably be optimized as well, but I'm just trying to get it to work first. Everything works short of this weird button behavior.

Using jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.11.1

Here is the full jQuery:

```
jQuery("#regExpander").click(function() {
            if ($('#regExpander:contains("begin registration +")').length) {
                $('#regExpander').text("hide registration –").toggleClass('lbActive').css({transform: 'translateX(-140px)'});
                $( "#regInfo" ).fadeOut( "slow", function () {
                    jQuery("#pageContents").slideToggle(900, 'easeInOutCubic');
                });
            } 
            else if ($('#regExpander:contains("hide registration –")').length){
                $('#regExpander').text("begin registration +").css({transform: 'translateX(0)'}).toggleClass("lbActive").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
                jQuery("#pageContents").slideToggle(900, 'easeInOutCubic', function () {
                    $( "#regInfo" ).fadeIn( "slow", function () {
                    });
                });
            } 
});
```

Comment: could it happen that your `:hover` state has the same CSS styling as your `:active` or `:focus`?

Comment: include a complete html example with related css - preferebly a working one http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Florian : Nope, all the CSS is pristine. Not sure why, but all of a sudden Firefox started behaving correctly (and I frequently dump all caches and relaunch every so often). Safari is the browser not playing nice now, though haven't checked Chrome to see if it's a webkit only problem. I'll do some more testing and check back. I'll try and put up some more of the code before I crash tonight.

Comment: Yep, it's a webkit problem. I'll still post the code and a video link to show the results. Opera, Chrome, and Safari all exhibit the same behavior. In fact, Opera and Chrome also leave a "snail trail" of the hover state background color until the button is pressed a second time. I could animate with jQuery but was trying to optimize for mobile. A simple slide of 100px might not be too bad though.